# Hide empty Columns to right based on filter

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a worksheet that has a lot of empty cells and many columns.

Basically, I want to filter a column, and based on the filtered value, hide the columns which have a blank cell in the corresponding row that was filtered.

I have an example below. We will call the sheet "task list"?  So basically if I filter column B for Eric, Column C, E, G, H, and I should be hidden. Then un-filtering should un-hide these columns.

I'm not too experienced with VBA, but it seems that it may be a worksheet vba based solution?

[image: Example]
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you have no data below the filtered data.

First setup the filter and then run:

```
Sub HideStuff()
    Dim i As Long
    Columns.Hidden = False
    For i = 3 To 9
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Columns(i).Cells) = 1 Then
        Columns(i).Hidden = True
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

We test against **1** because the only visible data *(in a candidate column)* should be the *header*
This can also be easily modified to operate on an event.